# stars: add band based on existing band calculations

Tags: r, stars

I would like to add an additional band to a stars object that includes information from two existing bands.

```
library(stars)
library(tidyverse)

toy_data <- reduce(rerun(2, {
  m <- matrix(sample(seq(0, 100, 1), 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
  dim(m) <- c(x = 5, y = 4)
  st_as_stars(m)
}), c) %>% merge()
```

what I want to achieve is:

```
toy_data$X[,,1] <- ifelse(toy_data$X[,,1]<40 & toy_data$X[,,2]>60, 1,0)
plot(toy_data %>% slice(attributes, 1))
```

However, I would like to create a new band with the values (3rd band) and do it preferably with `mutate` and `if_else` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work on the slices rather than the matrix versions then your new layer is going to be:

```
L3 = slice(toy_data,"attributes",1) < 40 &
     slice(toy_data,"attributes", 2) > 60
```

Then you can update your `toy_data` this way.

```
toy_data = merge(c(split(toy_data),L3))
```

Then

```
plot(slice(toy_data, "attributes", 3))
```

shows 0s and 1s.

There may be a prettier way to do this. But wrap it in a function and change the logic when someone answers with it.